# Linked List with data type of a struct

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, declaration

How do I declare an instance of the linked list with the data type of a struct in main?
For example... I am supposed to have a class with a struct that holds info. The linkedlist is supposed to have a data type of the struct. This is the instruction: The DVD class has the structure and one of its data members is an instance of the linked list with that structure as the data type.

```
class DVD
{
private:
struct disc
{
int length;
string name;
};
```

Linked List

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList1 
{
private:
// Declare a structure
struct discList
{
    T value;
    struct discList *next;  // To point to the next node
};

discList *head;     // List head pointer

public:
// Default Constructor
LinkedList1()
{ head = NULL; }


// Destructor
~LinkedList1();

// Linked list operations
void appendNode(T);
void insertNode(T);
void deleteNode(T);
void displayList() const;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all you have to do is to specify the type between angle brackets, like this:
`LinkedList1<DVD> myLinkedList;`

**EDIT:**

Here is what is happening behind the scene, the compiler will replace each `T` with `DVD`.

getting back to your code we get this:

```
struct discList
{
    DVD value; // You used to have T here
    struct discList *next;  // To point to the next node
};
```

and you will have a linked list where each node is a structure holding a `DVD` value.

Comment: I understand that `LinkedList1<DVD> myLinkedList;` will cause the class `DVD` to be the data type of the linked list but I need the struct `disc` to be the data type of the linked list. Or is it because `struct disc` is a part of `class DVD` that `LinkedList1<DVD> myLinkedList;` will work? Some one else told me to make my struct public. I am not at home to test it.

Comment: This is the instruction: The DVD class has the structure and one of its data members is an instance of the linked list with that structure as the data type.

Comment: Thank you. The clarification was nice. This is the way I had it but I guess the instructions "with the structure as the data type" was throwing me off. UpVote

Answer (score 0):

The name of the structure shall be accessible for the template class.

You could define this structure separatly and use its definition simultaneously in class DVD and as the template argument of the template class, For example

```
struct disc
{
int length;
string name;
};


class DVD
{
private:
   disc obj;
};
```

and then

```
LinkedList<disc> l;
```

Or you could define a public typedef for structure disc in class DVD. For example

```
class DVD
{
private:
struct disc
{
int length;
string name;
};
public:
  typedef disc disc_t;
};


LinkedList<DVD::disc_t> l;
```